# JAVA: What to do when getDefaultScreenDevice() returns null value?

Tags: java, null, awt

I have the following code:

```
private GraphicsDevice vcl;
GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
vc = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
```

and the problem is that getDefaultScreenDevice() method returns null value.

So what are the alternative ways to get the "GraphicsDevice" instance of "defaultScreenDevice" 
 or is there any particular setting for the GPU is required?

What should I do?

Answer (score -1):

GraphicsEnvironment is a type. I think you have to declare a variable with type GraphicsEnvironment and call getLocalGraphicsEnvironment() on that variable.

```
private GraphicsEnvironment ge;
GraphicsEnvironment env = ge.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
```

Comment: Nope. java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment is abstract and provides a static see the document java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment